# Close propertyPane in sharepoint framework

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-framework, spfx-custom-property-pane

I'm using the following command to open my propertyPane in SharePoint Framework.

```
this.context.propertyPane.open();
```

But there is sadly no `close()` option, so is there another way to close/hide the propertyPane again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, no good option available right now to close the property pane via API.

But then you can use `document.querySelector` to find the close button element and then programmatically trigger the click event.

You can modify from below sample code:

```
if(this.context.propertyPane.isPropertyPaneOpen()){
  var element = document.querySelector("button[class*='propertyPaneClose_']") as HTMLButtonElement;
  if(element != null){
    element.click();
  }  
}
```

Have used it in the `onPropertyPaneFieldChanged` to check whether a particular property was set to the value and based on that i triggered the property pane close event like below. Here, I am checking whether the `description` property equals `Hi` and if that's the case, i check if the property pane is open and then i close the property pane :

```
protected onPropertyPaneFieldChanged(propertyPath: string, oldValue: any, newValue: any): void {
    if (propertyPath === 'description' && newValue) {
      if(newValue == "Hi"){
        this.properties.description = newValue;        

        if(this.context.propertyPane.isPropertyPaneOpen()){
          var element = document.querySelector("button[class*='propertyPaneClose_']") as HTMLButtonElement;
          if(element !=null){
            element.click();
          }          
        }
      }      
    }
}
```

Would ideally like to have the `close` method available via SPFx but since this is not yet available, you can use this workaround.

**Update**

As Vardhaman mentioned in comments, looks like they have added the `close` method in the later versions. You can use it as:

```
this.context.propertyPane.close();
```

Comment: `this.context.propertyPane.close();` is available now. It must have been introduced in one of the recent versions.

Comment: Awesome, updating the answer !